# Breadcrumbs from menu URL

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I have implemented breadcrumbs in Drupal 7, using the following code in mytheme.inc file. It is working fine for all the custom pages but for a particular content type lets say CT1, I have url alias setup as homepage/page2/page3/[node:title] so the breadcrumb trail display as homepage > page2 > page3 > title of content but it is only displaying as homepage > title of content. Please advise what I am missing here to make it work the way I want.

```
function mytheme_breadcrumb($variables)
{
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
    $crumbs = null;
    if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
        $array_size = count($breadcrumb);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $array_size) {
            $crumbs .= '<li>' . $breadcrumb[$i] . '</li>';
            $i++;
        }
        $crumbs .= '<li class="active">' . menu_get_item()['title'] . '</li>';
        return $crumbs;
    } else {
        return '<li class="active">Homepage</li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try a community solution for this like [breadcrumbs by path](https://www.drupal.org/project/breadcrumbs_by_path)

Your custom function isn't doing anything with the url path itself, it's just using the breadcrumb variable. You can get the path with:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . request_uri();
```

Then you could split by '/' and use drupal_set_breadcrumb to set it.